# one row for each unique customer ID/affiliate id

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am using oracle 11g. can someone please tell me who can I get only one row for each unique customer ID/affiliate id in the output.

Input data from a oracle table:

- customerID   affiliate id    address state   phone   type

  42084    100 123 walton  il  xx  business

  42085    101 124 walton  ak  xx  personal

  42084    100 83 nw st    ny  xx  business

  42086    102 84 sw   ny  xx  ext

  42084    100 123 walton  il  xx  business

  42086    100 123 walton  il  xx  business

  82084    100 123 walton  il  xx  business

  42084    101 124 walton  ak  xx  personal

  42085    100 123 walton  il  xx  business

  42084    103 83 nwst ny  xx  inc

  42087    103 83 nw st    ny  xx  inc

Expected output:

customer ID affiliate id    address state   phone   type

42084   100 123 walton  il  xx  business

42084   101 124 walton  ak  xx  personal

42084   103 83 nwst ny  xx  inc

42085   101 124 walton  ak  xx  personal

42085   100 123 walton  il  xx  business

42086   102 84 sw   ny  xx  ext

42086   100 123 walton  il  xx  business

42087   103 83 nwst ny  xx  inc

Comment: Did you try using DISTINCT clause?

Comment: I tried distinct, so far working for me. since I am on oracle 11g, I am also trying with rownumber() over partion by or listagg. now sure if wm_concat is still supported by oracle

Answer (score 2):

you want to use partition by on CustomerID and AffiliateID column
like this...

```
select * from (select customerID,affiliateid,address,state,phone,type,
                 row_number() over(partition by CustomerID,AffiliateID
                            order by CustomerID,AffiliateID) r from xyzz)
 where r=1
```

here

```
select * from (select customerID,affiliateid,address,state,phone,type,
                     row_number() over(partition by CustomerID,AffiliateID
                                order by CustomerID,AffiliateID) r from xyzz)
```

this query return all the rows with row number,partition by CustomerID
and AffiliateID

like this..r-is row number

```
CustomerID      AffiliateID        add       state      phone    r

   10              456             xyz         xx         00     1
   10              456             xyz         xx         00     2
   10              456             xyz         xx         00     3
   10              123             xyz         xx         00     1
   20              456             xyz         xx         00     1
   20              789             xyz         xx         00     1
   20              789             xyz         xx         00     2
   30              789             xyz         xx         00     1`
```

set the row number for all the column

```
where r=1
```

the where clause return the rows which is set to 1
and eliminate duplicate rows

Answer (score 0):

Just use
    `SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, AffiliateID
     FROM [TableName]`

This will return values where(CustomerID, AffiliateID) combination is unique.
If you need to include other fields in your result you can go with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY CONCAT(CustomerID, AffiliateID);
```